# Using the LEFT Function with the LEN Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to write a function the will cut off the first 4 chars in a field. For example if the value of the field is `ABC_123_EFG` it would return `123_EFG`. I have tried to use a combination of the [LEFT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx) and [LEN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329.aspx) functions but haven't had any success.

Here is what I think it should be ...

```
RIGHT(code, LEN(code) - 4) AS code_concat
```

But it fails with this error

```
Msg 536, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
Invalid length parameter passed to the RIGHT function.
```

What am I doing wrong? Is this the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: will all values always be at least 4 characters long?

Comment: Is `code` at least 4 characters long in *all* the rows under consideration?

Comment: Just looked at it, it can be null ... opps

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx):

```
 substring(code, 5, 1000)
```

Or, if it's a `varchar(max)`:

```
 substring(code, 5, len(code))
```

Comment: Except it should be 5, not 4. String function are 1-based.

Answer (score 3):

try this..

```
select isnull(RIGHT(code, LEN(code) - 4),'') AS code_concat
```

Answer (score 1):

[stuff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) is nice little function that is quite useful when modifying strings.

```
select stuff(code, 1, 4, '')
```